# Dynamic Variable creation and using the Same variable in a loop in Shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am stuck with a Requirement but stuck in a Scenario, tried out lot of alternatives from Google but looks like not serving my Purpose.

Below is my Requirement-

tablename=$1
This is a Variable for which the value i get from the command line.

Now my requirement is i want to create a variable with the Name which i received in the variable called tablename.

And i want to use that variable in a loop further.

For Example :

Say,

tablename = dept1

Now my loop will look something like-

for dept1 in .... do
...
done

Can someone please help me with this..

Comment: `eval "$tablename"="\"dept1 variable value\""` ? It is unclear what your're asking. Can you please rephrase the question? Add more details? Post some code that you've tried?

Comment: I fail to see what link you need between the value of `tablename` and the name of the index variable in the `for` loop.

Comment: I mean to say my piece of code will be called with different different parameter values with different different tablenames concurrently at the same time.. So i want my loop variable to be of different different names for each called instances